# ajax сменить radiobox

Tags: ajax

Всем доброго времени суток, нужно средствами аякс по нажатию на кнопку "Отменить" переключить **radiobox** с положения yes на no

```
<input  type="radio" id="display_conf" name="confirm" value="yes">ДА
<input  type="radio" id="display_conf" name="confirm" value="no" >НЕТ

<a id="cancel" >отменить</a>
```

Comment: А при чем здесь *Ajax* ?

Comment: раз написал значит надо это сделать аяксом чисто по своим соображениям и работы сайта не буду употребляться в подробности

Comment: Без подробностей вам тут никто ничем не поможет. Это во первых, а во вторых *ajax* для смены значения? Не поленитесь написать детальнее , у вас инпуты и кнопка на одной странице находятся? Если да то это делается одним предложение на *javascript*, а вот при чем тут *ajax* так и остается загадкой для меня.

Comment: да все на одной страницы находится, кнопка отменить просто должна сбрасывать значение на NO и закрывать форму которую значение YES открывает, вот для этих соображений и нужно

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, включите, пожалуйста, подробности в текст вопроса. Также было бы неплохо уточнить, форма в Вашем случае, это тег `div`, у которого изменяются соответствующие свойства (какие?)?

Comment: форма в теге DIV но не суть, мне просто нужно по нажатию на id="cancel" сменить положение input на NO

Comment: Если просто переключить `input`,то AJAX здесь ни при чём. Всё делается гораздо проще.

Comment: спасибо за диалог но я уже все сделал очень просто и аяксом, на примере ответа ниже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается без AJAX. Переключение `input`:

**JavaScript:**

```
function fun()
{   
    $('#display_conf[value="no"]').prop('checked','true');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="cancel" onclick="fun()" >отменить</a>
```

Comment: это то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Или так: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGzRGm

HTML

```
<input  type="radio" id="display_conf" name="confirm" value="yes">ДА
<input  type="radio" id="display_conf" name="confirm" value="no" >НЕТ
<br>
<a id="cancel" style="cursor:pointer;color:#00f;">отменить</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){

$('#cancel').on('click', function(){
  $("input[value='no']").prop({
  checked: true
});
});

});
```